# Foregin key for sqlite in windows phone

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am trying to create a foregin key for a table by using classes.I have a class name person (it is a table name in my db).

class Person
    {
       [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int ID { get; set; }

```
    public string DoctorName { get; set; }

    public string Date { get; set; }

    public string Time { get; set; }

    public string Prescription { get; set; }

    public string Image { get; set; }

    public string Audio { get; set; }
```

}

another class name is prescription so in need to foreignkey for the person id in this class.
So can you please help me

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Check out these links

- http://wp.qmatteoq.com/a-new-sqlite-wrapper-for-windows-phone-8-and-windows-8-the-basics
- http://wp.qmatteoq.com/a-new-sqlite-wrapper-for-windows-phone-8-and-windows-8-relationships/

The links specify a [wrapper](http://sqlwinrt.codeplex.com/) which can be used to access SQLite in WP8 an implement FK.